# Indicate which build upload to Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, archiva

I'm doing a simple configuration with Jenkins to generate my deploy, the pom file has been configured to create WAR and JAR file. What I want now is to upload automatically the JAR file to my Maven repository (using Archiva currently), but until now I can't find properly information for doing this.
The routine is trying to upload the WAR file instead.

Comment: Usually you define in your parent pom a distributionManagement and in your build you simply say `mvn deploy`..?

Comment: you can upload your artifacts to any artifact registry such as nexus, jfrog etc by issuing `mvn deploy`?

Comment: Usually, both files will be uploaded, but the jar file gets a classifier. What are you doing to generate the jar?

Comment: @khmarbaise my pom has <packaging>war</packaging>, so what you suggest is to change this to jar instead?